# Homogeneous functions are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $r\in\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x>0\}$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function s.t. $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^rf(x)$ for all $\lambda\geq 0, x\in\mathbb{R}$(in this context homogeneous of degree $r$).

I need to show that $f$ is continuous.

I already tried to construct a contradiction for the definition of continuity over limits of sequences but this keeps leading me to dead ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for $x\geq0$,
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=f(x\times 1)=x^r\,f(1). 
\end{align}
For $x<0$, 
$$
f(x)=f((-x)(-1))=(-x)^rf(-1)=(-1)^rx^r\,f(-1). 
$$
Now continuity follows directly at $x\ne0$ by continuity of the exponential, and at $x=0$ by noting that both lateral limits are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=a$. Let
$$
\mathrm{sgn}(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
-1, & \mbox{ if } & x<0\\ 
0, & \mbox{ if } & x=0\\ 
+1, & \mbox{ if } & x>0\\ 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f( x_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty} f( |x_n|\cdot \mathrm{sgn}(x_n))=\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_n|^{r}\cdot f(\mathrm{sgn}(x_n))= |a|^r\cdot f(\mathrm{sgn}(a))=f(|a|\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(a))=f(a)
$$